# How to make an image fade out by itself in a few seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, fadeout

i got a button to show an image in the UIImageView. what i need to do is to get this image to fade out by itself in 2 seconds, is it possible to do so?

here is my code on the button:

```
    - (IBAction)A {
    UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AString.png"];
    [ImageView setImage:Img];
}
```

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)A 
{
     UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AString.png"];
     [ImageView setImage:Img];

     Img.hidden = NO;
     Img.alpha = 1.0f;

     [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
         Img.alpha = 0.0f;
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         Img.hidden = YES;
     }];
}
```

Comment: I think the duration of the animation would be 2 seconds without delay :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
yourImageView.hidden = YES;    
[UIView transitionWithView:yourImageView
                      duration:2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Called on parent view
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
```

Comment: hi there this makes the image fade in within two seconds and it does not disappear. when i hit the button, i need the image to be shown in 100% opacity instantly, and then it needs to fade out in 2 seconds